# WCF and Linq Service

Tags: wcf, linq, service

i am making wcf rest service using linq. i wanna use stored procedure to access the database in linq..i came to know to about the accessing syntax but ToList() property i m not finding in my project..can anybody suggest me the solution ?

---

Code :  [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/CList/")]
    public CList[] GetCList()
    {string strConnection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["HConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

```
    HDataContext dc = new HDataContext(strConnection);

    string strUrl = WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest.UriTemplateMatch.RequestUri.ToString();

    var result = from cust in dc.tbl_Customer_Masters

                 select new CList
                 {
                     RMSID = 0,
                     CID = cust.C_Id,
                     FIRSTNAME = cust.C_First_Name,
                     LASTNAME = cust.C_Last_Name,

                 };

    return result.ToArray(); }
```

Comment: sorry ToList() Property*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ToList()` **method** is only defined for objects that inherit from `System.Linq.Enumerable` or that implement the `IEnumerable` interface. So, you need to make sure of the following:

1. You have a reference to the appropriate DLL in your project (it's in System.Core, so you should have a reference by default unless you removed it).
2. You have a using directive for the `System.Linq` namespace in your file.
3. The object you're trying to call `ToList` on actually inherits from `System.Linq.Enumerable` or implements the `IEnumerable` interface.

Comment: System.Core is not added what is the physical location of it ?

Comment: when i add system.core.dll its giving error : Could not load file or assembly 'System.Core' or one of its dependencies. This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded.

Comment: You need to be targeting .NET 3.5 or above to reference it.

Answer (score 0):

ToList is an [Extension Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx). This means it's not actually in the containing class. You need to add a using statement to your code to use this feature.

```
using System.Linq;
```

Then you can call ToList() on any IEnumerable

Comment: its added in the VS 2008 project by default and its already there...then also m not finding it..